# Fragment Recycler view onclick show popup

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have an activity with recyclerview  that extends fragment activity.

[image]

When an item is clicked from a recyerview, i want to get the title and display it as a pop up message.

i tried several ways but noting works. cam some one help me to do this TNX.

**PickupActivity**

```
public class PickupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private navigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment;

    ApplicationEnvironmentURL applicationEnvironment;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Context context;
    String BASEURL;
    String FilteredData;
    String AllAgents;

    public String ProfileId;
    public String companyId;
    public String profileToken;

    private com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton pik_fab1;
    private com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton pik_fab2;
    private com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton pik_fab3;
    private com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton pik_fab4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Dashboard");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pickup);

        applicationEnvironment = new ApplicationEnvironmentURL(this.context);
        context = this.getApplicationContext();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_dashboard);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (navigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);


        pik_fab1 = (com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.pickup_delete);
        pik_fab2 = (com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.pickup_close);
        pik_fab3 = (com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.pickup_assignto);
        pik_fab4 = (com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.pickup_pickup);
        pik_fab1.setOnClickListener(this);
        pik_fab2.setOnClickListener(this);
        pik_fab3.setOnClickListener(this);
        pik_fab4.setOnClickListener(this);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("zupportdesk", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String islogged = prefs.getString("islogged", "Not defined");
        String userid = prefs.getString("userid", "Not defined");
        profileToken = prefs.getString("profileToken", "Not defined");
        companyId = prefs.getString("companyId", "Not defined");
        String companyName = prefs.getString("companyName", "Not defined");
        ProfileId = prefs.getString("ProfileId", "Not defined");

        Log.d("islogged     : ", islogged);
        Log.d("userid       : ", userid);
        Log.d("profileToken : ", profileToken);
        Log.d("companyId    : ", companyId);
        Log.d("companyName  : ", companyName);
        Log.d("ProfileId    : ", ProfileId);

        getTickets(ProfileId, companyId, profileToken);

        View newTicket = findViewById(R.id.newtic);
        newTicket.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.pickup_pickup:
                    Log.d("Fab_clicked", "Pickup Ticket");
                    pickupTicketMessage("Are you sure you want to pickup the selected tickets?", "Confirm?");
                break;
            case R.id.pickup_close:
                    Log.d("Fab_clicked", "close tickets");
                    closeTicketMessage("Are you sure you want to close the selected tickets?", "Confirm?");
                break;
            case R.id.pickup_delete:
                    Log.d("Fab_clicked", "close tickets");
                    DeleteTicketMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the selected tickets?", "Confirm?");
                break;
            case R.id.pickup_assignto:
                    Log.d("Fab_clicked", "Assign to Agent");
                try {
                    assignTicketstMessage("Select an agent");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    /* Multiple Button on click event handle */
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.newtic:
                    // Create a login URl, before starting anything

                    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                        Intent intentTicket = new Intent(PickupActivity.this, NewTicket.class);
                        startActivity(intentTicket);
                    } else {showErrorMessage("Please check your internet connection.", "No Connectivity!"); }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


    public void getTickets(String profileId, String companyId, String profileToken) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            try {
                setFilteredDataURL(companyId, profileId);
                FilteredData = new getFilteredData().execute(profileToken).get();
                // adding the filtered data to shared preferences for further use.
                //adding user data to shared preferences.
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("zupportdesk", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("FilteredData", FilteredData);
                editor.commit();

                Log.d("ZF-Filtered_Data", FilteredData);
                setTicketsURL(profileId, companyId);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            new getNewTickets().execute(profileToken);
        } else {
            showErrorMessage("Please check your internet connection.", "No Connectivity!");
        }
    }


    private void PickupTicket() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray TicketsArray = new JSONArray();

        List<Integer> selected_item = new ArrayList<>();

        for (PickupTicketsItemObject ticket : PickupActivityFragment.support_ticket) {
            if (ticket.isSelected()) {
                    selected_item.add(Integer.valueOf(ticket.getTicket_id()));
                    TicketsArray.put(Integer.valueOf(ticket.getTicket_id()));
            }
        }

        Log.d("pickup_ticket_size", String.valueOf(selected_item.size()));
        if(selected_item.size() < 1){
            Log.d("pickup_ticket_size", "empty");
            //Show Error Message
        }else {
            Log.d("pickup_ticket_size", "have tickets");

                jsonObject.put("TicketID", TicketsArray);
                jsonObject.put("ProfileId", ProfileId);
                jsonObject.put("CompanyID", companyId);

                setPickupTicketURI();
                Log.d("ZF-PickupTicket", String.valueOf(jsonObject));

           new TicketPickupRequest().execute(String.valueOf(jsonObject), profileToken);
        }
    }







    private void showSuccessMessage(String data, String title){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(data)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // restart Activity
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.notification_success)
                .show();
    }


    private void assignTicketstMessage(String title) throws JSONException {

        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setTitle(title);

        final List<String> agentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> agentProfileIDList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(AllAgents != null && !AllAgents.isEmpty() && !AllAgents.equals("null")) {

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(AllAgents);
            int count = jsonarray.length();
            Log.d("Full Agents", String.valueOf(count));


            for (int k = 0; k < jsonarray.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject5 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(k);
                Log.d("Agent object ", String.valueOf(jsonobject5));
                agentList.add(jsonobject5.getString("FirstName"));
                agentProfileIDList.add(jsonobject5.getString("ProfileId"));
            }
            String[] types = new String[agentList.size()];

            for (int j = 0; j < agentList.size(); j++) {
                types[j] = agentList.get(j);
            }

            b.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("Selected_no ", String.valueOf(which));
                    Log.d("Selected_agent ", String.valueOf(agentList.get(which)));
                    Log.d("Selected_profile_id ", String.valueOf(agentProfileIDList.get(which)));

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    assignTicketstMessage2(String.valueOf(agentList.get(which)), String.valueOf(agentProfileIDList.get(which)));
                }
            });

            b.show();
        }
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Settings.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        if(id == R.id.home){
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.notification){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    private void showErrorMessage(String data, String title) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(data)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.notification_red)
                .show();
    }

    private void showErrorMessageNoInbox(String data, String title) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(data)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.notification_red)
                .show();
    }


    public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

......................... More
```

**PickupActivityFragment**

```
public class PickupActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ArrayList<PickupTicketsItemObject> support_ticket;
    public static RecyclerView Ticketslist;
    PickupActivity pick_up_activity;



    public PickupActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pickup_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        pick_up_activity = new PickupActivity();

        Ticketslist = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.pickup_list);
        Ticketslist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        Ticketslist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        pick_up_activity = new PickupActivity();

    }

}
```

**PickupTicketsAdapter**

```
public class PickupTicketsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PickupTicketsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<PickupTicketsItemObject> all_tickets;

    public PickupTicketsAdapter(List<PickupTicketsItemObject> tickets) {
        this.all_tickets = new ArrayList<>(tickets);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_pick_tickets, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindData(all_tickets.get(position));

        //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(all_tickets.get(position).isSelected());

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                all_tickets.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return all_tickets.size();
    }



    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public ImageView priority;
        public TextView sts_open;
        public TextView sts_overdue;
        public TextView tkt_from;
        public TextView tkt_subject;
        public TextView tkt_assignedto;
        public TextView tkt_created_date;
        public TextView txt_ticket_id;
        public CheckBox checkbox;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.pick_checkbox);
            priority = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.priority_status_icon);
            sts_open= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_opn_status);
            sts_overdue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_overdue);
            tkt_from = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_from);
            tkt_subject = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_subject);
            tkt_assignedto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_Assignedto);
            tkt_created_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_Created_date);
            txt_ticket_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_TicketID);
        }

        public void bindData(PickupTicketsItemObject ticket) {

            priority.setImageResource(ticket.getStatus_priority());
            sts_open.setText(ticket.getStatus_open());
            sts_overdue.setText(ticket.getStatus_overdue());
            tkt_from.setText(ticket.getTicket_from());
            tkt_subject.setText(ticket.getTicket_subject());
            tkt_assignedto.setText(ticket.getTicket_assignedto());
            tkt_created_date.setText(ticket.getTicket_created_date());
            txt_ticket_id.setText(ticket.getTicket_id());
        }

    }
}
```

**PickupTicketsItemObject**

```
public class PickupTicketsItemObject {
    private int status_priority;
    private String status_open;
    private String status_overdue;
    private String ticket_from;
    private String ticket_subject;
    private String ticket_assignedto;
    private String ticket_created_date;
    private String ticket_id;
    private boolean isSelected;


    public PickupTicketsItemObject(){

    }

    public int getStatus_priority() {
        return status_priority;
    }

    public String getStatus_open() {
        return status_open;
    }

    public String getStatus_overdue() {
        return status_overdue;
    }

    public String getTicket_from() {
        return ticket_from;
    }

    public String getTicket_subject() {
        return ticket_subject;
    }

    public String getTicket_assignedto() {
        return ticket_assignedto;
    }

    public String getTicket_created_date(){return ticket_created_date;}

    public String getTicket_id(){return ticket_id;}

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public void setStatus_priority(int status_priority) {
        this.status_priority = status_priority;
    }

    public void setStatus_open(String status_open) {
        this.status_open = status_open;
    }

    public void setStatus_overdue(String status_overdue) {
        this.status_overdue = status_overdue;
    }

    public void setTicket_from(String ticket_from) {
        this.ticket_from = ticket_from;
    }

    public void setTicket_subject(String ticket_subject) {
        this.ticket_subject = ticket_subject;
    }

    public void setTicket_assignedto(String ticket_assignedto) {
        this.ticket_assignedto = ticket_assignedto;
    }

    public void setTicket_created_date(String ticket_created_date) {
        this.ticket_created_date = ticket_created_date;
    }

    public void setTicket_id(String ticket_id) {
        this.ticket_id = ticket_id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

public void onBindViewHolder(.....)

- for particular TextView and use AlertDialog to show message inside adapter.

Comment: so simple. TNX.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is make changes in your adapter class

In your ViewHolder class, declare a CardView object as well.

Then in the onBindViewHolder method you can set the holder.cardview.onClickListener

You can use alert dialog builder for showing popups